# Creating a comma seperated column in python based on two column range values

Tags: python, pandas

I need to create a new column having values from column1 value (start) to column2 (end) value in intervals python
For example, I have an interval range 0 to 5
My dataframe has column1 value (start) 3 and column2 value (end) 50 
I need to create a column with comma seperated value 3,4,5,0,1,2,3,4,5.... total 50 of such values
How can I create that?

Comment: I have edited the code

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools as it
l = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
first = 3
end = 50
col = []
c = it.cycle(l)
begin = next(c)
while begin != first:
    begin = next(c)

col. append(begin)
for i in range(first,end-1):
    col.append(next(c))
```

col comes out 
[3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1]